# MySQL's session handler difficulties

Tags: php, mysql

Watching [this online tutorial](https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Opening-session-reading-stored-data/382572/415833-4.html) about MYSQL's session handler and got really confused about this part:

`table_XXX` == Table XXX;
`col_XXX` == Column XXX;
`sid` == Session id

Read method:

```
public function read($session_id)
    {
        $this->db->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED');
        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        /**
         * the data is selected and no other ppl can interfere
         * the writing process until COMMIT is reached
         */
        $sql = "SELECT $this->col_expiry, $this->col_data
                FROM $this->table_sess
                WHERE $this->col_sid = :sid FOR UPDATE";
        $selectStmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $selectStmt->bindParam(':sid', $session_id);
        $selectStmt->execute();
        $results = $selectStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($results) {
            if ($results[$this->col_expiry] < time()) {
                // return empty if data out of date
                return '';
            }
            return $results[$this->col_data];
        }

        return $this->initializeRecord($selectStmt);
    }
```

Protected method:

```
protected function initializeRecord(\PDOStatement $selectStmt)
    {
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table_sess 
                    ($this->col_sid, $this->col_expiry, $this->col_data)
                    VALUES (:sid, :expiry, :data)";
            $insertStmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $insertStmt->bindParam(':sid', $session_id);
            $insertStmt->bindParam(':expiry', $this->expiry); // expiry is defined
            $insertStmt->bindValue(':data', '');
            $insertStmt->execute();
            return '';
        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            $this->db->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Write method:

```
public function write($session_id, $data)
    {
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table_sess ($this->col_sid,
                    $this->col_expiry, $this->col_data)
                    VALUES (:sid, :expiry, :data)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    $this->col_expiry = :expiry,
                    $this->col_data = :data";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':expiry', $this->expiry, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sid', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            if ($this->db->inTransaction()) {
                $this->db->rollback();
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

In 'Protected method', line 8, there is a $session_id, and clearly no $session_id is passed to the protected method, so bindParam() for that line simply binded nothing?
So initializeRecord() simply initiated a row that has expiry time but nothing else? And then the sid and data is inserted after write method is called?

Comment: You don't pass a session_id argument to the protected method but you do to the other methods. That is why it is empty I guess.

Comment: @Cagy79 So you are saying that the author is just trying be consistent?

Comment: @Cagy79 Also, am I right about the last two questions?

Comment: "So you are saying that the author is just trying be consistent" --- nope. The author has not run their code. Or run then with notices disabled.

Comment: @zerkms I see, thank you ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doing a lot of string-construction trickery with `WHERE $this->col_sid = :sid` and so forth, as it creates SQL statements.

You might try echoing or dumping those SQL statements to see what they contain right before you run `->execute()` on them. That will help you troubleshoot.

It's pretty clear your protected method is missing `$session_id`. Is it possible there's a value for `$this->sid` you could use there?

Comment: I guess this is the best answer here

Comment: This code here is actually the author's code, and there's no $this->sid